# powershell output results from a script to log file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a simple bit of Powershell code which pings servers if they are up and then disables the local admin account. How can I output the results to a log file so that I have record of what I have disabled.

This is what I have so far

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -filter {OperatingSystem -like "Windows Server*"} | 
ForEach ($computer in $computers) {     
   $rtn = Test-Connection -CN $computer -Count 1 -BufferSize 16 -Quiet    
  IF($rtn -match 'True') {
    write-host -ForegroundColor green $computer | Disable-localUserAccount -ComputerName $computer -username Administrator
  } ELSE {
      Write-host -ForegroundColor red $computer
  }     
}
```

Comment: What have you tried in attempting to write out to a file? Doing so is *very* easy with PowerShell, and there are multiple ways to do it.

Comment: I have tried this but not sure that is the right way to do this     $outputstring = $computer 

  $outputstring -join "," >> C:\Create_Adminuser_computers.csv

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Write-Host` writes directly to the console. That output cannot be redirected to a file. Replace it `Write-Output` and drop the fancy coloring if you want to redirect the output to a file. Also, I'd pipe the computer list into a `ForEach-Object` loop, so you can directly write the output to a file. And `Test-Connection` returns a boolean value, so you can use it directly in the conditional:

```
$computers | % {
  if (Test-Connection -CN $_ -Count 1 -BufferSize 16 -Quiet) {
    Write-Output "$_ online"
    Disable-localUserAccount -ComputerName $_ -username Administrator
  } else {
    Write-Output "$_ offline"
  }     
} | Out-File 'C:\path\to\your.log'
```